Converting Back Clip Model Output Embedding Image Array To Image
I am working on using a clip model for multimodal RAG application with big dataset that take time to load, saving the embedded output array " 1 D " into a lance db table, instead of retrieving the target image by calling the index of the image from the main dataset, can i convert the array back to an image ?
I attempted to reconstruct the image using the 1D array but was not successful
Dataset input : Image
Output of Clip: Embedded vector
User Input: Text to query
Final output: loop up DB and retrieve image
Example of the image embedded vector:
array([ 1.17210817e+00,  5.74196398e-01, -1.14204817e-01, -5.10777414e-01,
       -7.74219096e-01,  7.89542854e-01,  3.18113387e-01,  5.38914025e-01,
        1.70747519e-01, -1.03527451e+00, -1.34498207e-02, -5.79562843e-01,
       -3.70207489e-01, -7.53472805e-01,  6.78899288e-01, -1.24533996e-01,
        1.03758955e+00, -8.19651708e-02,  1.69559613e-01, -3.30640823e-01,
        6.85019493e-01, -4.11322385e-01, -3.72525185e-01, -8.90218616e-01,
       -2.41921097e-01,  3.36437762e-01,  1.87242851e-01,  6.74522996e-01,
        8.99704453e-03, -2.97694594e-01,  6.83088005e-01,  7.00277627e-01,
        5.59891105e-01, -2.78847247e-01,  2.98040092e-01,  4.66321379e-01,
       -4.05163825e-01, -2.79652596e-01, -3.56837839e-01,  7.98298180e-01,
        1.02180111e+00, -3.19189906e-01, -8.69058788e-01, -5.98645985e-01,
        6.52047098e-01,  8.48272204e-01,  4.54363078e-01, -2.48686492e-01,
       -2.24289149e-01, -3.99510056e-01,  1.38743684e-01,  3.04309484e-02,
        1.95495099e-01,  3.63456011e-01,  2.34081179e-01,  3.00543383e-02,
       -1.39479905e-01, -6.81636155e-01, -2.55430341e-01, -8.18648696e-01,
        8.02083239e-02, -2.86239237e-01,  8.89072776e-01,  3.20573509e-01,
        1.45787144e+00,  5.28937340e-01, -9.10780072e-01, -1.89953700e-01,
       -3.98142219e-01,  7.74143562e-02,  6.96751056e-03,  8.37407589e-01,
        1.75480142e-01, -6.83544934e-01,  4.41908389e-01, -2.58560181e-01,
       -1.63062632e-01,  1.70535401e-01,  8.77007842e-01,  2.89610893e-01,
       -2.23356709e-01, -3.02972913e-01, -7.41017580e-01,  1.00572640e-02,
       -7.73119748e-01, -2.56960750e-01,  5.55947013e-02,  6.13526642e-01,
       -5.26746631e-01, -1.44166306e-01,  3.30064744e-01,  3.32210958e-01,
        2.60478377e-01, -6.00262523e-01,  3.32966484e-02,  5.03078580e-01,
       -5.29121697e-01,  1.18389420e-01, -2.27990806e-01, -2.48838931e-01,
       -2.78886974e-01, -1.30412892e-01,  1.28678620e-01,  1.53773472e-01,
        5.80283940e-01, -3.41618568e-01, -4.12355632e-01,  4.91128787e-02,
        2.85881042e-01,  1.09745991e+00,  8.83679092e-01, -6.68036118e-02,
        5.11967838e-01,  1.43337831e-01,  3.97554368e-01,  7.51022220e-01,
       -5.12716830e-01, -1.06739044e+00, -8.10726047e-01, -9.32563424e-01,
        2.81657845e-01, -1.17005420e+00, -6.97951913e-01,  9.64582562e-02,
       -1.54325202e-01, -6.54569924e-01, -2.29774311e-01,  9.14789796e-01,
       -3.90121341e-01, -8.34066123e-02, -3.42053808e-02,  4.27138537e-01,
        3.41080099e-01, -1.49325728e-01,  5.41557260e-02, -5.99580348e-01,
       -3.38299572e-01, -2.36232460e-01, -5.74045539e-01,  3.32578957e-01,
       -1.85196042e-01, -2.69040376e-01,  3.12881097e-02,  1.58388138e-01,
       -3.41052492e-03, -2.66403615e-01, -6.78564966e-01,  4.43132669e-01,
       -3.81891817e-01,  5.42755544e-01,  5.07486820e-01, -1.86559260e-01,
        8.34269077e-02,  4.79191281e-02, -1.34117931e-01,  8.76402199e-01,
       -1.01589501e-01,  9.62280035e-01, -5.81635088e-02, -1.00298321e+00,
       -2.24224731e-01,  1.23817587e+00,  1.79812521e-01,  3.40546593e-02,
       -2.69596845e-01, -2.10569039e-01, -3.71231854e-01,  1.73365027e-01,
        5.27877510e-01,  7.90809393e-01, -1.03433526e+00, -5.65046489e-01,
       -7.46627092e-01, -1.68057829e-01,  3.90457213e-01, -5.07460535e-01,
        2.96588093e-01, -1.18626438e-01,  7.88899243e-01, -1.72064189e-04,
        9.98990536e-01,  2.15279952e-01,  3.54412466e-01, -1.83522493e-01,
       -5.93322992e-01, -4.22120780e-01,  2.07163349e-01,  2.68834773e-02,
        1.29317832e+00,  3.02036315e-01,  2.60526925e-01,  5.59995621e-02,
       -5.44297636e-01, -2.46924624e-01, -4.34307232e-02,  3.29303741e-01,
       -7.61722624e-01,  2.69599378e-01,  2.92440236e-01, -2.09984899e-01,
        2.78568178e-01,  7.66959488e-02, -1.42107397e-01,  4.61626977e-01,
        3.85595948e-01,  2.76500672e-01, -4.49946582e-01, -2.86034554e-01,
       -5.04181147e-01, -3.80594105e-01,  5.89592218e-01,  6.38373613e-01,
       -8.39762539e-02,  2.28806958e-01, -2.51331836e-01,  2.85306185e-01,
       -9.31459442e-02,  3.02096367e-01,  2.40553752e-01,  1.89531133e-01,
       -1.75590932e-01,  1.16381064e-01,  5.73644698e-01,  3.46514255e-01,
        1.12710265e-03,  6.85892940e-01, -3.58577132e-01,  2.11136863e-01,
       -4.51947689e-01, -6.81253791e-01, -3.71718138e-01, -1.14872165e-01,
       -7.81943142e-01,  2.52310574e-01, -6.69196201e-03,  5.66537917e-01,
       -5.61945736e-01,  6.30643815e-02,  2.12954000e-01,  5.86553812e-01,
        2.74233580e-01,  2.84010321e-01, -3.71363223e-01,  1.68670975e-02,
        2.26360038e-01,  4.36086744e-01, -4.56781566e-01,  9.20120239e-01,
       -2.88685501e-01,  2.83534765e-01,  5.69103658e-01, -2.43777975e-01,
        5.04309595e-01, -4.18538183e-01,  3.63618694e-02, -7.35053197e-02,
       -6.90204278e-02,  3.26981992e-01, -2.41325468e-01,  9.12784040e-02,
       -1.04754305e+00, -8.71735692e-01, -8.87956917e-01,  3.01926076e-01,
       -1.27476597e+00,  1.06433809e-01,  5.00401147e-02, -6.99066043e-01,
        4.59845722e-01, -2.63056666e-01,  3.26069891e-01,  1.54281735e-01,
        1.01224400e-01,  7.69949853e-02,  6.60520643e-02, -2.16050178e-01,
       -1.66539326e-01, -5.14584422e-01, -8.41088235e-01, -3.63557428e-01,
       -1.42131314e-01, -3.71827751e-01, -2.02541530e-01, -4.58959192e-01,
        1.66900530e-01, -2.99056917e-01,  3.86544690e-02,  2.30679840e-01,
        2.34038338e-01, -3.74841154e-01, -4.37735587e-01, -6.23795211e-01,
       -5.65041363e-01, -1.22159310e-01, -2.35510662e-01, -3.06135323e-02,
        1.45707637e-01,  3.91342819e-01,  7.53825903e-01, -5.01385629e-01,
       -2.26398438e-01,  3.24470341e-01,  2.52449751e-01, -6.81720734e-01,
       -1.68359533e-01,  9.77148563e-02, -3.24867100e-01,  3.83370191e-01,
       -1.48434833e-01,  7.25615442e-01, -9.28008378e-01, -6.84687376e-01,
       -3.77725184e-01,  3.85481119e-02, -5.22336841e-01,  4.65947613e-02,
       -1.25258815e+00,  1.53083906e-01, -2.73961276e-01,  7.30177909e-02,
        7.79586494e-01, -2.22847253e-01, -3.54111969e-01, -6.26195133e-01,
        2.01543331e-01, -2.96642520e-02, -7.07510889e-01, -4.51001108e-01,
       -5.31803906e-01,  2.21828654e-01,  8.00025016e-02,  1.63786098e-01,
        3.34535450e-01, -2.04980955e-01, -5.19218445e-01,  3.95734370e-01,
       -2.15402797e-01, -2.68657476e-01, -9.57909226e-01,  2.92957276e-01,
        7.18270391e-02,  2.81237304e-01,  5.15978873e-01, -1.59877986e-01,
       -2.91102454e-02,  1.09780587e-01, -1.15206468e+00, -1.07594490e+00,
       -1.98598146e-01,  4.84243602e-01, -3.02083552e-01,  6.81200698e-02,
       -3.71264480e-02, -2.62949198e-01,  2.30749995e-01,  3.39279771e-02,
        5.59233904e-01,  2.71585494e-01,  8.70169103e-02, -2.46951088e-01,
        7.38950133e-01,  3.18448037e-01, -5.28358817e-01, -3.57265770e-01,
        2.64704019e-01,  6.68446794e-02, -4.55861807e-01, -3.81440133e-01,
        6.46440148e-01, -3.60307872e-01, -7.40671158e-01, -6.73986375e-02,
        3.28639209e-01,  7.03081936e-02,  2.02598661e-01, -1.85374558e-01,
        3.91111434e-01, -1.25293821e-01,  1.26894563e-01, -1.04960181e-01,
        1.16907692e+00,  2.36559793e-01,  2.55639136e-01, -3.01347375e-01,
       -3.62643152e-01, -3.55058759e-01, -2.24589258e-01, -4.07300115e-01,
       -4.09749985e-01,  2.89716423e-02,  6.28487229e-01,  3.09788078e-01,
       -1.65211812e-01,  1.06274498e+00, -6.88763678e-01, -3.15002836e-02,
       -8.73758048e-02, -9.61672187e-01,  3.58716607e-01,  1.39114544e-01,
       -1.98159665e-01,  7.80767620e-01,  2.64901906e-01, -4.89348054e-01,
       -7.03722179e-01, -3.97832841e-01, -3.61937314e-01, -6.81160271e-01,
       -1.84885576e-01,  6.04743540e-01, -1.70128807e-01, -1.12212636e-01,
       -1.13489598e-01, -7.79652977e+00, -3.17459665e-02, -5.90703428e-01,
       -8.45140889e-02,  6.71959579e-01, -6.04701102e-01, -4.62140858e-01,
        4.18965131e-01,  2.60652184e-01, -5.25118411e-01,  6.56949639e-01,
       -1.41037092e-01, -7.24403322e-01,  3.22658792e-02, -3.83326679e-01,
        2.21456528e-01, -1.10259101e-01,  2.21990630e-01, -1.68058217e-01,
       -2.29119390e-01,  4.00653750e-01,  8.26423764e-01, -2.58792251e-01,
       -4.25292701e-01, -1.86002955e-01,  2.17124626e-01,  8.52257967e-01,
        1.11144376e+00,  3.45847756e-02, -4.25674647e-01, -4.03524518e-01,
        5.39147854e-01,  6.65305555e-01, -1.51129290e-01,  2.06734702e-01,
        5.91614723e-01,  1.07837170e-01,  6.30376860e-02, -6.80443823e-01,
        4.62679267e-01, -8.94454718e-01, -2.00071901e-01, -1.85243309e-01,
       -2.52795309e-01,  1.39419623e-02, -2.27420643e-01, -5.01923621e-01,
       -2.59068340e-01, -4.19572771e-01, -2.56596059e-01,  8.59189630e-02,
       -4.81638879e-01, -7.38943458e-01,  3.84757727e-01,  1.14849901e+00,
       -8.79521593e-02, -7.78139651e-01, -1.82377726e-01,  2.71003962e-01,
        7.37630963e-01, -2.06681699e-01, -4.21610996e-02,  1.47178739e-01,
       -2.54979551e-01,  3.31646591e-01, -3.78990054e-01, -7.02991605e-01,
       -4.64025289e-01, -4.71818566e-01, -5.30530691e-01,  8.13651681e-02,
        3.39634597e-01, -2.12392360e-01,  3.81359637e-01, -9.02056515e-01,
       -4.14011061e-01, -4.76262212e-01, -3.46838176e-01, -3.37714672e-01,
       -6.62892997e-01,  2.14351580e-01,  3.11172694e-01,  4.30924267e-01,
        1.21914834e-01, -1.78283025e-02, -1.25835329e-01,  3.39576721e-01,
       -9.16984230e-02,  2.45325267e-01,  5.28382659e-01,  7.03870416e-01,
        6.26848757e-01,  9.23272967e-03,  8.28442693e-01,  6.02577507e-01,
        5.49551070e-01, -3.43499631e-01,  3.28853220e-01,  1.82382360e-01,
        2.60140598e-01, -1.89453121e-02,  5.35849571e-01, -7.72928670e-02,
       -5.70111685e-02, -5.39802611e-01, -2.53254592e-01, -2.20628735e-02,
       -5.66717088e-01, -1.21778965e-01,  3.72472793e-01, -1.10950701e-01,
       -6.15912855e-01,  3.23249280e-01,  4.54417855e-01,  2.30562449e-01,
       -2.34056735e+00, -3.89847249e-01, -3.76775749e-02, -1.75626576e-01,
        4.06519085e-01, -4.57537174e-01,  1.03506684e+00, -4.53015089e-01,
        5.57108939e-01, -7.76289344e-01, -2.58215696e-01, -8.12376440e-01,
        2.78393477e-02,  2.10922770e-02, -3.03443938e-01,  3.49930406e-01,
       -6.62334085e-01, -2.90921301e-01, -1.89533725e-01, -5.99764407e-01,
        8.64029408e-01, -2.48159692e-01, -2.97091365e-01,  8.86078000e-01,
        4.52950485e-02,  1.19512486e+00, -1.11614168e+00, -4.28958461e-02,
       -1.68809962e+00, -1.65832832e-01, -4.64020908e-01,  3.88011113e-02,
       -4.14929926e-01,  5.65912127e-01, -7.18433484e-02,  6.43876016e-01,
       -1.15721428e+00,  3.27025384e-01,  1.94017768e-01, -3.65139931e-01,
       -1.49699658e-01,  5.54466307e-01, -1.06009088e-01,  2.94309318e-01,
       -9.83775795e-01, -1.41447112e-01,  7.25972235e-01,  5.78576922e-02,
        8.58490169e-01, -2.72591859e-01, -6.07338727e-01, -2.27685779e-01,
        7.25577235e-01,  1.53927833e-01, -6.80570602e-01, -1.03785551e+00,
       -5.97702444e-01, -6.46217108e-01,  1.11712289e+00, -2.10003823e-01,
       -7.44306207e-01, -1.66145936e-01,  3.66996638e-02,  2.32614353e-01,
       -5.05304217e-01, -1.00625598e+00,  2.86073089e-02,  6.19638324e-01,
        1.19397365e-01,  1.60416424e-01,  1.25474492e-02, -6.94084346e-01,
       -1.03909767e+00,  3.20954651e-01, -5.26805043e-01,  5.79967737e-01,
       -3.35343003e-01, -3.51786137e-01, -3.81894380e-01,  2.32978329e-01,
        4.59691137e-02,  6.40899479e-01, -2.34982029e-01, -2.74435580e-01,
       -3.38657260e-01,  1.68984592e-01,  4.27410394e-01, -4.73404229e-01,
       -2.49087587e-02, -5.02387524e-01, -1.59987092e-01, -2.87931025e-01,
        4.59878922e-01,  1.21118002e-01,  6.95940971e-01,  1.87038377e-01,
        1.10105097e-01, -4.93666567e-02,  2.68167228e-01,  6.88324392e-01,
        1.42492279e-01, -3.90288621e-01,  2.43435726e-02,  8.11592937e-01,
        3.13662201e-01,  1.47580132e-01,  8.60756993e-01,  1.10638928e+00,
       -1.29849136e-01,  6.47528350e-01,  4.38966006e-01, -1.45656049e-01,
       -2.93278307e-01,  1.99029893e-01,  4.46431160e-01, -5.51785007e-02,
        8.31562233e+00, -8.59883651e-02,  7.72810400e-01,  1.96057096e-01,
        7.58247375e-01, -6.88266575e-01, -2.26376295e-01,  5.02551258e-01,
       -7.17716888e-02, -3.81480530e-02,  1.02062547e+00, -4.75003988e-01,
        1.51782874e-02, -6.24782205e-01,  4.03439075e-01,  1.70003951e+00,
       -3.07306975e-01,  2.87628204e-01,  6.36167228e-01, -2.36462742e-01,
        2.80675620e-01,  4.41092849e-01,  1.46143019e-01,  4.94826436e-01,
        4.37330425e-01,  1.01191652e+00,  9.21043754e-01, -3.52128178e-01,
        3.24033916e-01, -4.41262275e-01, -1.81030989e-01, -3.14925194e-01,
       -5.03862262e-01, -2.62931079e-01,  2.17970356e-01, -9.69461858e-01,
        2.13052481e-02,  4.42230523e-01, -3.61417860e-01, -4.63960022e-01,
       -2.45286480e-01,  1.11746304e-01,  9.44133922e-02,  1.87140003e-01,
        3.65078807e-01,  7.50894189e-01, -1.56975806e-01,  4.00103837e-01,
        1.32351243e+00, -2.01969519e-01,  2.92355239e-01,  3.46666753e-01,
       -1.19994663e-01, -6.51092887e-01,  4.46209818e-01, -4.56474006e-01,
       -1.41980127e-01, -4.04539376e-01,  7.03505993e-01,  3.21337849e-01,
        5.09681880e-01,  6.80097342e-01, -8.76447372e-03, -1.94639802e-01,
       -7.17939317e-01,  2.56714880e-01,  7.36490712e-02, -2.22466275e-01,
        2.26695705e-02,  8.47303689e-01, -3.48875783e-02, -7.16958046e-02,
       -5.51655777e-02, -6.91358224e-02, -5.30577421e-01, -6.64020479e-01,
       -3.40236157e-01, -5.65868914e-01, -4.47656244e-01, -2.57127857e+00,
       -1.27904743e-01,  9.56078410e-01, -6.42802060e-01, -4.18957204e-01,
       -2.09852964e-01,  4.73359466e-01, -1.12198874e-01, -1.07536450e-01,
        1.42472193e-01,  1.05935419e+00,  3.30237836e-01, -3.93535823e-01,
       -5.87579645e-02,  6.48692191e-01,  3.04990709e-01, -2.73603648e-01,
       -2.57641613e-01,  1.54582839e-02,  6.66288495e-01,  3.11900675e-01,
       -1.54791832e-01,  2.85760239e-02, -1.50334224e-01,  6.12803362e-02,
       -9.10575464e-02,  4.81033772e-02,  9.77103770e-01,  7.92777240e-01,
        2.30489708e-02,  3.09747398e-01,  3.39013159e-01, -7.12340623e-02,
        3.44327569e-01, -1.23697549e-01,  2.35457912e-01,  3.82291764e-01,
       -8.46556902e-01, -2.44571641e-01, -1.68473735e-01,  5.07801533e-01,
       -4.89749968e-01,  7.20392019e-02,  6.50379956e-01, -8.00699964e-02]

I tried to reconstruct the image, but did not work
Original size of the image: (1680, 1050)
